# Can i run same command concurrently from different chats using async function?

Tags: async-await, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

I recently started playing with discord bots and I have one doubt in it that is it mandatory to use `async` functions for discord commands. if it is then can someone tell me the difference (according to a discord bot behavior)

Answer (score 7):

Synchronous basically means that you can only execute one thing at a time. Asynchronous means that you can execute multiple things at a time and you don't have to finish executing the current thing in order to move on to next one. Here's an example of asynchronous programming.

```py
import asyncio
import random

async def my_coroutine(id):
    process_time = random.randint(1, 5)
    await asyncio.sleep(process_time)

    print(f'Coroutine: {id}, has succesfully completed after {process_time} seconds')


async def main():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(10):
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(my_coroutine(i)))

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Sample output

```
Coroutine: 4, has successfully completed after 1 seconds
Coroutine: 7, has successfully completed after 2 seconds
Coroutine: 8, has successfully completed after 2 seconds
Coroutine: 0, has successfully completed after 3 seconds
Coroutine: 1, has successfully completed after 3 seconds
Coroutine: 2, has successfully completed after 4 seconds
Coroutine: 6, has successfully completed after 4 seconds
Coroutine: 3, has successfully completed after 5 seconds
Coroutine: 5, has successfully completed after 5 seconds
Coroutine: 9, has successfully completed after 5 seconds
[Finished in 5.0s]
```

The coroutines go off and execute concurrently and finish execution at different times, it's important to note that these are **not** completed in the same order as they were submitted.

Here's the same code in normal sync programming

```py
import random
import time

def work(id):
    process_time = random.randint(1, 5)
    time.sleep(process_time)

    print(f'Function: {id}, has succesfully completed after {process_time} seconds')


def main():
    for i in range(10):
        work(i)


main()
```

Sample output

```
Function: 0, has successfully completed after 5 seconds
Function: 1, has successfully completed after 3 seconds
Function: 2, has successfully completed after 4 seconds
Function: 3, has successfully completed after 2 seconds
Function: 4, has successfully completed after 3 seconds
Function: 5, has successfully completed after 4 seconds
Function: 6, has successfully completed after 2 seconds
Function: 7, has successfully completed after 5 seconds
Function: 8, has successfully completed after 5 seconds
Function: 9, has successfully completed after 1 seconds
[Finished in 24.0s]
```

All functions finish in the same order as they were called.

Basically, if the library was written in normal sync code, you wouldn't be able to use multiple commands/events at the same time, you'd need to wait till the previous one it's finished, and call the next one.

Comment: according to your answer if i have one command that takes 10 seconds to execute so if i hit that command from both servers then they will get executed one by one but if i hit 2 different commands at a time they will get executed parallely.

Comment: but in my case its not happening as you said